# Database translations with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

After  thinking a lot how to support i18n  i came up with one of the accepted solutions to have a seperate table.
**Problem with Translatable**
I installed Translatable from doctrine extensions as suggested but didnt work as i want and experienced users adviced me against using it. Even when having a seperate table it has the translatable columns in both main table and translations table and stores the values in an eav way. Also in case default locale changes (that happened to me and may happen again) it makes things complicated as default values at main table dont seem to have a specified locale.Also i have several translatable fields (5~).That would result in 5 or even more left joins in case of fallback.

**Other Solution**
The other solution i thought is having a separate table with translations only for each table and set the default locale and fallback maybe via a postLoad event listener.This way i could call obj.getTitle() without obj.translations['en'].getTitle() ,no need to provide locale.

**The problem**
The problem with this approach is the fallback.One workaround is during join to add a "WITH locale in ('en','de') for example.This would return lots more data but fallback would work. The other way would be using coalesce but it is impossible for doctrine to map it at entity. Is there any way to implement fallback effiently ?

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look to https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable, which is the best solution we've found after digging a lot into it.

We're currently using it for many entities, and it works pretty well.
You can query translations as any other entitiy, joins, using DQL for example.

And yes, you could easilly imagine a fallback maechanism, using existing api.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about the fallback mechanism with the knplabs' API? I couldn't find anything on the documentation.

Comment: fallback to default locale is already provided at php level: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/DoctrineBehaviors/Model/Translatable/TranslatableMethods.php#L91

Comment: If you want to implement this at sql level, using coallesce, or IF (for example), you could use native queries.

Comment: That's an quite an old post. However, am digging into it at present.

Comment: @Gaurav You could try https://github.com/vm5/EntityTranslationsBundle
I like it because it's native Doctrine ORM - translations are with associations, no 1 big table for all translations of all entities. It's code is also very lightweight.