# Can you please simplify (or help me refactor) my logic

Tags: symfony, localization, doctrine

I am aggregating data in json to convert it into symfony object.

A category (otology) has a type (swimming pool, restaurant). This category has a description that is translated into several languages.

I would like to be able to simply do getXXX('fr'), to have this description in French, getXXX('en') for English.

With a repository I think I can do it, but maybe I complicate it:

My class Otolongy:

```
class Ontology
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $idOntology = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'ontology', targetEntity: Label::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'],  fetch:'EAGER')]
    private Collection $descriptions;
```

my class label (for fields description):

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LabelRepository::class)]
class Label
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $label = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'descriptions')]
    private ?Ontology $ontology = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'labels',  fetch:'EAGER')]
    private ?Lang $lang = null;
```

my class lang:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LangRepository::class)]
class Lang
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 10)]
    private ?string $labelLang = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'lang', targetEntity: Label::class)]
    private Collection $labels;
```

You can see that for my tests I had to put fetch:'EAGER' I'm not convinced that this is the right way to do it... well after all put 1 eager or have to make a 'complex' request in my controller it should be equivalent...

[image]

I have already done this system on java and I had made a map key, so I used this command ontology.description.get(lang) in the template, in order to use the local as an argument and java gave me the description in the good language.

if i can avoid loading the ontology in eager i think the display of twig will go faster? Namely that I must also check that the translation in the visitor's local exists, otherwise I must display by default (English or French)

So my goal is to use the visitor's locale to know which language (language of the ontology in the database) that twig should display. Is there maybe a simpler way to do it? Maybe I'm totally wrong?!

Comment: Did you check out the [i18n](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) section of doctrine/symfony?

Comment: would that mean that I have to save my ontology in the database in only 1 language and create (automatically) a translation file?

Comment: I already have the translation I don't want to retranslate things

Comment: I don't understand how this is possible. So yes ok for static 'hello word' fields but it's data updated every day so how to do it

Comment: You can use a database for the translations - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423786/database-translations-with-doctrine)